# Debug Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, debugging

#### Scenario

I've got a windows service written in C#.
I've read all the google threads on how to debug it, but I still can't get it to work.
I've run "PathTo.NetFramework\InstallUtil.exe C:\MyService.exe". It said the install was successful, however when I run "Services.msc", The service isn't displayed at all, anywhere. If I go into Task Manager, there is a process called "MyService.vshost.exe". Pretty sure that's not it, because it's a service, not a process.

#### Can Someone Explain To Me?

If I am supposed to see the service when I run Services.msc?
(Bearing in mind this is all being done on a local machine, with no servers AT ALL.

#### Other

I'm running VS2008.

#### EDIT:

This is all being done on my local machine, I have no servers or access to any.
Also, I don't even know what the service does, I want to debug it so I can walkthrough the code and see how it all works (the code inside the service, not the service itself - for any of you smarty pants that might suggest I look at a template).

#### EDIT 2:

NONE OF THESE ARE WORKING!
Everytime I try something I get some message about having to use NET START or install the service.

#### EDIT 3:

I'm running VS2008.

I typed this:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.exe

I got this:
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 2.0.50727.3053
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\dev\Restarter\bin\
Release\Restarter.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\EDT.Restar
ter.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.exe
   logfile = C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.InstallLog

The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\dev\Restarter\bin\
Release\Restarter.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restar
ter.InstallLog.
Committing assembly 'C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.exe
   logfile = C:\dev\Restarter\bin\Release\Restarter.InstallLog

The Commit phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>

I then went to RUN -> Services.msc
I can see nothing in there.

There is a process in Task Manager called "Restarter.vshost.exe".

That's it.

I only wanted to install and debug it.
I know it works (as it it runs and doesn't crash).
But the code was written by a friend and I want to understand the underlying code by walking through it in debug mode.

Comment: you trying to debug deployment/installation or runtime issues ?

Comment: your edits are confusing.  It sounds like your first issue is to get the service running.  please post the exact command line you used to install the service, and the response.

Comment: have you tried creating a new service using sc.exe?  the format should be something like:  sc create NameToGiveTheService binPath=PathToExe.  Not sure if you need to do that with managed services or not.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192.  It should appear in the services list.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I recommend following pattern for debug:

```
 var ServiceToRun = new SomeService(); 
 if (Environment.UserInteractive)
 {
    // This used to run the service as a console (development phase only)

    ServiceToRun.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to terminate ...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    ServiceToRun.DoStop();
 }
 else
 {
    ServiceBase.Run(ServiceToRun);
 }
```

**Edit:** make sure that your target is Console Application, not Windows Application, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: That is nice, I used to is a `#define X` and `#if X` to control run as a service versus running as a console app, this is definitely more elegant and cleaner.  I wish I could vote it up a few more times.

Comment: +1 I don't have a .Start method on my services so I added 1. Hope it's not something I'm missing out on

Comment: The console doesn't show up, and Stop() is triggered right away.

Comment: @guiomie debug it step by step, it should not really be like that, either console should be opened or it runs as a service until terminated.

Comment: @Andrey I had to modify the project properties from Windows Application, to Console Application, then it worked.

Answer (score 24):

you can debug it by attaching the debugger to the process.  You can do this by either adding a line to the startup of your program:

```
Debugger.Launch ();
```

after adding the using statement:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

you will either need to put that in a  conditional block or remove it when you are done debugging

or by running the service and then attaching to the process manually from the IDE: Debug->Attach to process..

Comment: This is an amazing find for me I suggest that everyone use this but there is a catch. You need to remove this before rollout so I suggest wrapping this in if #DEBUG #endif... provided you roll out in release :)

Comment: I use this approach in combination with supplying an argument at runtime (via Service Control Manager -> right click -> Properties -> General tab -> Start parameters). You can check for the parameter value (in `OnStart`, for example) with: `if (args != null && args.Any(s => s == Debugcommand))  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();  `. If you don't supply a 'start parameter' then your service will run without breaking to the debugger, so no need to #ifdef.

Comment: I still get the error that I can not debug a windows service while using this method, even when changing my output to console application.

Answer (score 6):

We can make the windows service project debuggable by just adding a parameter and making it behave like a console app.

1) Go to your windows service project properties -> Debug -> Start Options 
2) Give an argument -Console
3) Go to Application tab -> output type, change it to Console Application
4) Type the below code in Program.cs

```
static class Program
    {
        private static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle;
        private static Service1 _service;
                static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool runConsole = false;**

            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                if (arg.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("-console"))
                {
                    runConsole = true;
                }
            }   

            _service = new Service1();
            if (runConsole)
            {
                _waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Workflow Service in Console Mode");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to exit Console Mode");
               Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(OnCancelKeyPress);
                _service.InternalStart();
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { _waitHandle });
            }

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }

        static void OnCancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _service.InternalStop();
            _waitHandle.Set();
        }


    }
```

Comment: In your Service1.cs file add a method internal void InternalStart() { OnStart(null); } and a stop method internal void InternalStop()
        {
            OnStop();
        }

Answer (score 5):

This has helped me a lot when developing/debugging windows services:

http://windowsservicehelper.codeplex.com/

Just press F5 to debug. Very easy.

Andrey's approach is also very good.

Comment: The most easy way to debug windows service.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to debug my service without deploying it, I always write it in the following way:

In your program.cs file:

```
#if DEBUG
    MyService myService = new MyService();
    myService.OnDebug();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#else
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new MyService()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
```

and in your MyService.cs file:

```
    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }
```

***  NOTE  ***: You must build under 'Release' mode when you are finally done with debugging and you are ready to deploy the service otherwise the service will not be considered as a service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is nice, but I find that the first answer does a better test of the OnStart() and OnStop() methods within the service. As long at you add the Start() and DoStop() methods to your service and then call the OnStart and OnStop overrides from them because of the OnStart/OnStop protection level.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions:**

1) You have the source code available in a Solution in the VS2008 IDE

**How I Debug C# Services:**

1. Install the Service using `InstallUtil`. (You seem like you've already done that)
2. (If Needed) [Change the Service path](http://www.gringod.com/2006/11/14/service-path-to-executable/) to the MyService.exe that is produced in your Solution's `bin` folder
3. Put something like the following at the beginning of your Service's `OnStart()` method:

   ```
   while(true)
   {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
   }
   ```
4. Put a breakpoint on `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)`
5. Build the Solution
6. Start your Service using the [Windows Service Utility](http://www.theeldergeek.com/services_guide.htm)
7. While your Service is starting, in VS2008 goto `Debug -> Attach To Processes...`
8. Make sure `Show Processes From All Users` and `Show Processes In All Sessions` are checked
9. Find your MyService.exe in the list, and click `Attach`
10. You should now be at the breakpoint you inserted in the infinite loop
11. Drag the Control (Yellow Arrow) *just* outside the infinite loop
12. Debug away!

**Disclaimer:**

Remember to remove the infinite loop when you want to release a build, or when you simply want to run the service normally.

Comment: Also make sure your build mode is 'Debug' and the path for step 2 (in Onion-Knight's answer) also points to bin/Debug/YourService.exe

Comment: Hi! But the VS2010 doesn't let me drag the control outside the loop!

Comment: @ZoomIn there is functionality **Run to Cursor** or _Ctrl+Shift+F10_

Answer (score 1):

It can be that service name is not what you expect and that's why you can't find it. Service name is defined in `ServiceInstaller` properties in .NET project and does not have to correspond with executable name in any way. But if you're sure the service is not listed after installation, here is what you can do.

First, service installation. There are 2 methods, `InstallUtil.exe` and `SC.exe`. First one is tailored specifically for .NET services as it will run all `ProjectInstaller` and `ServiceInstaller` code. Second one will not do that but it will give you more options and is usually more effective i.e. likely to succeed where `InstallUtil` fails. This can be when there is an exception in any installer code.

You've already tried installing with `InstallUtil` so here is `SC` version:

```
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\Service.exe"
```

Note that `MyService` is the name **you** give to the service at this point and it can be anything you like (within reason :-). This name will be shown in services console list.

Once you have your service installed you would need to debug it right when `OnStart` is called. This can be achieved by running and attaching to a debugger (Visual Studio) from within the service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    #if DEBUG
    Debugger.Launch();
    #endif
    ...
}
```

Do not forget to build and replace service executable after this code change. Service must be stopped but no need to uninstall and reinstall it.

To delete service using `SC`:

```
sc delete MyService
```

Answer (score 0):

If your business layer is seperate from the windows service you can test all of your business functions outside of running the windows service.

To test the windows service I like to create a test project that is a console app and I start a new thread that runs my service.

```
System.Threading.Thread sftpThread = new System.Threading.Thread((ThreadStart)service1);
service1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently added this to a project and it works great for me.  You can debug it just like any other EXE.  After it is added go to your project properties and add a command line parameter (/EXE) in the Debug tab for the Debug build configuration.

```
<MTAThread()> _
Shared Sub Main()

    '' 
    '' let's add a command line parameter so we can run this as a regular exe or as a service
    ''
    If Command().ToUpper() = "/EXE" Then
        Dim app As MyService = New MyService()

        app.OnStart(Nothing)
        Application.Run()
    Else
        Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

        ' More than one NT Service may run within the same process. To add
        ' another service to this process, change the following line to
        ' create a second service object. For example,
        '
        '   ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase () {New Service1, New MySecondUserService}
        '
        ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New MyService}

        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add `/test` on project properties debug tab as a start option. Then you can run your service without having to install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your service with TopShelf you should be able to easily debug it from Visual Studio