# Windows Service hosting WCF Library: app.config connectionStrings

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF Library and I'm trying to host it within a Windows Service.

When testing just the Library with WCF Test Client all is well.  In my Library project I have an app.config with `<connectionStrings>` in the `<configuration>` element.  I am specifying the location of a local database like so:

```
data source=C:\test\smMonitorLocalDB.sdf;
```

I have copied everything from the app.config in my Library project to the app.config in my Windows Service project EXCEPT the `<connectionStrings>` section.  Because, if I add that `<connectionStrings>` section, my Windows Service won't start.

If I leave out the `<connectionStrings>` section, my Windows Service starts just fine.  It also works just fine ( except the parts of it that depend on the `<connectionStrings>` ).

So my question is: where should I be adding my `<connectionStrings>`?  Or is there a better way for me to be going about this?

Comment: Can you debug and see why it can't start?

Comment: The error is happening in or before the `OnStart()`, of the Service, so I can't see what's happening.

Comment: Any data in error message? Log records (consider using EventViewer)?

Comment: Can you add the app.config code?

Comment: I checked out the EventViewer.  It was surprisingly helpful.  OK, found that the app.config of my Windows Service didn't like having an `<entityFramework>` tag in it.  Now my service will start so I can debug it.

Comment: It turns out that I simply didn't understand _when_ the Windows Service read the app.config file.  I ASSumed that it would read it each time that it started.  However that was incorrect.  It only reads the app.config when the Windows Service is _installed_.  The way I eventually got there started by checking on things in the EventViewer.  Thanks for your help.   @J0HN, if you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @davehale23 you've found the answer yourselves, so just add it and mark it as correct, it would be useful if someone face the same problem in future. My role in finding it was quite minor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `app.config` file is only read when the Windows Service is INSTALLED.  I had originally assumed that if the Windows Service was restarted that it would re-read the `app.config`.

If you are having difficulty trying to figure out why your Windows Service isn't starting, check out the [EventViewer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427), you may have some logs there.

It is very difficult to debug a Windows Service if it is not started, but it is possible.  Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629720/debug-windows-service) if you're having trouble.

Thanks to @J0HN for your help.