# Error 1053 "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am supposed to change the code for a VM-Manager in order that it can run on a new server. I changed all the addresses that referred to the old server but when I try to run the service I get the error message: Error 1053 "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion". I read that this error is supposed to appear after 30 seconds but I receive it immediately after starting the service. Here is the OnStart Method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        RequestAdditionalTime(150000);   
        WCFService.client.Connect("https://*************");
        WCFService.client.Login(@"*********", "***********");
        host.Open();
    }
```

I tried to increase the additional time but it didn't have any effect. There isn't the possibility for me to attach a debugger. Any suggestions how to approach this probem?

I have tried to put a try-catch around it:

```
try
        {
            RequestAdditionalTime(150000);
            WCFService.client.Connect("https://***********");
            WCFService.client.Login(@"********", "**********");
            host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\*********\Desktop\errorMessage.txt", e.ToString());
        }
```

But i received the same error message and no text file was created on the desktop.

I wanted to try this patern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2629741/2996227 but i don't really know where to put it. Should I put it into the "main" method of the programm?

Comment: You can debug windows services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629720/debug-windows-service

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand those solutions or they wouldn't work. My programm is not a console application (as far as I can tell) and I cannot attach a debugger.

Comment: It's a windows service isn't it?

Comment: I thought so since it appears in the "services" window after I removed the autostart from the wix-installer and installed it.

Comment: @BIDeveloper It's not really possible to debug this, since there is only milliseconds between attempting to start the service and receiving the error.