# windows service will not stop when I select stop from the services windows C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, backgroundworker

I have written a windows service but when I try to stop the service it says that the service cannot be stopped at this time. Here's my whole class:

```
public partial class RenewalsService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Thread _thread;

    public RenewalsService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CanStop = true; 
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(WorkerThread)
        {
            Name = "Renewals Service Thread",
            IsBackground = true
        };
        _thread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {

            if (!_shutdownEvent.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed)
            {
                _shutdownEvent.Set();
            }
            if (_thread.IsAlive)
            {
                if (!_thread.Join(3000))
                {
                    // give the thread 3 seconds to stop
                    _thread.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // _thread.Join may raise an error at this point. If it does we dont care. We dont care about any other exceptions
            // since we are already in the process of closing the service.

        }
        finally
        {
            IError logger = new Logger();
            Exception ex = new Exception("The Renewals service has been stopped.");
            logger.Log(this, SeverityEnum.Warning, ex);
            Environment.ExitCode = 0;
            Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
        }
    }


    private void WorkerThread()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(1))
            {

                string timeToRun = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunTime"];
                string[] timeStrings = timeToRun.Split(':');
                TimeSpan runtime = new TimeSpan(0, Int32.Parse(timeStrings[0]), Int32.Parse(timeStrings[1]), Int32.Parse(timeStrings[2]));

                if (DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay.Hours == runtime.Hours &&
                    DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay.Minutes == runtime.Minutes)
                {
                    Renewals renewals = new Renewals();
                    renewals.GenerateRenewal();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IError logger = new Logger();
            logger.Log(this, SeverityEnum.Warning, ex);
            this.OnStop();

        }

    }
}
```

What's missing to ensure the user can stop the service.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok to me, so here's a couple of things to check.

First, does the `GenerateRenewal()` method take a long time to complete?  If so, you might need to periodically check `_shutdownEvent` inside that method for a timely shutdown.  Of course, you've marked the thread as a background thread so it ***should*** shut down when you tell the service to stop anyway.  I haven't seen background threads hold up process termination, but I guess there's always that chance.

Second, the more likely culprit to me is that the service has already shut down due to an exception.  The Services console doesn't automatically refresh when a service shuts down, so it's possible you see the Stop link available to you when it shouldn't be.  If you hit F5, the console will refresh, and if your service has stopped, the Start link should be the only one available.  Check your log files to see if your exception handlers have been triggered.

### UPDATE

So it looks like your `WorkerThread()` method is throwing an exception, which causes the service to stop.  This explains why the Stop link is giving you the error message when you click it.

Providing you have sufficient permissions on your box, use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629720/debug-windows-service) to debug your service to find out why the exception is occurring.

HTH

Comment: I have added a call to the onStop() event outside of my while loop. This seems to have cured the problem to a sort. That is it now closes the service, but throws an error. ignore the error and the service then stops. Still cant see why though. I've checked all logs including those in the event viewer and all look ok. I can live with the error that get's thrown for now when the 'stop' button is pressed, but it would be nice to get to the bottom of why.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The base `ServiceBase` class calls your overridden virtual method `OnStop()` when the Windows Service Control Manager ("the SCM") has sent the service a "Stop" command. In the method's implementation you are supposed to do whatever is necessary to get your service to a stopped state, then return from the method back to the `ServiceBase` class, which handles the interaction with the SCM, in this case to tell the SCM that your service is now stopped. The SCM will decide when your service process should be terminated, and the `ServiceBase` class handles that without you needing to do anything explicit.

For a well-behaved service, you should either just return at the end of your `OnStop` method, or throw an exception. The `ServiceBase` class will handle things appropriately, including logging your exception, if you have thrown one, as an error in the Windows Event Log. If your method may take a while to get your service stopped, you should call `base.RequestAdditionalTime()` at the appropriate points, so the base class can tell the SCM that you haven't just hung, your service is in the process of stopping.

I think your main problem lies in these lines:

```
Environment.ExitCode = 0;
Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
```

You never return to the base class at all... so the `ServiceBase` class never has a chance to respond gracefully to the SCM... you are just unilaterally terminating the process hosting your service. This is not what a well-behaved Windows service does.

The `ServiceBase` class is designed to be able to support multiple services hosted in a single service process. Individual services should not concern themselves with the lifetime of the host service process, only with the logical state of their own service.