# How to debug Windows Service Applications in VS .NET

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to debug the Windows services in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629720/debug-windows-service)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629741/201303